# combining 3 subjects with combineLatest and return an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have 3 subjects. Would like to subscribe them, fill a global array of items with values from those Subjects and return this array as observable so all the components can subscribe. When i tried it with combineLatest couldnt get any results. Any ideas how to achieve this ?

```
 public loaditems() {
   return combineLatest(
      of(this.paginatorSuccessSub$).pipe(startWith(null)),
      of(this.sortSuccessSub$).pipe(startWith(null)),
      of(this.filtersSuccessSub$).pipe(startWith(null)),
    ).pipe(
      map(value => {
        const paginator = this.appendPaginators(value[0]); // method fills the global array of items
        const sort = this.appendSortedItems(value[0]);// method fills the global array of items
        const filters = this.appendFilters(value[0]);// method fills the global array of items
        console.log(paginator, sort, filters)
        return of(this._items)
      }))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`combineLatest` Takes `Observable` as input, `Subject` inherit from `Observable` so you just have to pass in subject without wrapping it with `of()`

```
  return combineLatest(
      this.paginatorSuccessSub$.pipe(startWith(null)),
      this.sortSuccessSub$.pipe(startWith(null)),
      this.filtersSuccessSub$.pipe(startWith(null)),
    )
```

Comment: tried, getting as console.log (null, null, null)

Comment: I think combineLatest wants an array of Observables though..(and what is this._items..??)

Comment: @MikeOne still no luck.. this._items is a global array which filled with result of those subjects. like subject gets the items, appending method is taking properties of those items, create a new object and push inside of the this_items array

Comment: That looks strange. Also, your combineLatest doesn’t seem to be returning the emitted values. I’m confused as to what you’re trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @tlq I think you should use `const paginator = this.appendPaginators(value[0]);const sort = this.appendSortedItems(value[1]);const filters = this.appendFilters(value[2]);` Also remember, `combineLatest` emits new value as soon as at least 1 observable emits the value.

Comment: @user2216584 thanks i made a mistake. But still there i dont get any output on console. its always null..

Comment: can it because your observables never emit any value apart from the startWith(null)